# Generating controls dynamically using placeholder

Tags: asp.net, .net

How can I create `divs` dynamically using placeholder in c#? I have declared placeholder inside of a repeater.

Is it possible to create controls dynamically in placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

here you go:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
     {
           PlaceHolder pl = e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
           if (pl != null)
           {
               HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div"); 
               div1.InnerHtml = "Hello"; 
               pl.Controls.Add(div1);
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: This would work with just a simple `PlaceHolder` control, but not one within a Repeater.

Comment: I would check to see if the `Item` is of `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItemType.AlternatingItem`

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically add a `div` to a `PlaceHolder` control within a `Repeater` control, you need to use the `ItemDataBound` event of the `Repeater`.

Within the method for `ItemDataBound` you will need to find the `PlaceHolder` control. Checking first if the `ItemType` is `ListItemType.Item` or `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` first.

```
PlaceHolder ph = (PlaceHolder) e.Item.FindControl("PlaceHolderControl1");
```

Then you can add the `div` as MUG4N has suggested.

```
HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
div1.InnerHtml = "Hello";
div1.Attributes.Add("class", "classname");
div1.Attributes.Add("style", "top: 10px; left: 20px;");
ph.Controls.Add(div1);
```

To add another `div`, just repeat from `div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");` down to `ph.Controls.Add(div1);`

Alternatively, you can add a `<asp:Panel>` control as this renders as a `<div>` on the page but is more ".net"

```
Panel panel1 = new Panel();
```

Then add a `<asp:Literal>` control to this.

```
Literal literal1 = new Literal() { Text = "Hello" };
panel1.Controls.Add(literal1);
ph.Controls.Add(panel1);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a class to that div s?

Comment: To add a class to a div that is generated via the `HtmlGenericControl` way you can use `div1.Attributes.Add("class", "classname");` If you are using the `Panel` option, it would be `panel1.CssClass = "classname";`

Comment: how could i add top, left styles for divs ?

Comment: ya .. i need to set top , left . for the divs . this divs contain tags .

Comment: and can you not do that through the css?

Comment: no . because i am reading values from a table and i will assign to the top,left

Comment: how can i create multiple divs dynamically? the above one is creating only one div . how can i create multiple divs

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your additional questions.